# WCF : I Keep getting the error "The caller was not authenticated by the service."

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication, wshttpbinding

I Keep getting this error while performing test with WCF Test Client :

> The caller was not authenticated by the service.

I tried to set the `security mode` to `none` on both side but the error still persisted

I can not use `basicHttpBinding` because from what I know it's in .Net 4.5

I've spent hours for this problem but still got no luck even though I've come through some similar topics on SOF also, but they didn't help!

Web.config :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="ota2010AEndpoint" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32"/>
                    <reliableSession ordered="true"/>
                    <security mode="None" />
                </binding>
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>

        <services>
            <service behaviorConfiguration="CalculatorServiceBehavior" name="GWork_Service.Service1">
                <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="GWork_Service.IService1" />
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
                <host>
                    <baseAddresses>
                    <add baseAddress="http://xxx:8000/" />
                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>
            </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="CalculatorServiceBehavior">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Client's app config :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IService1">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://xxx:8000/" binding="wsHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IService1" contract="GWork_MER.ServiceReference1.IService1"
          name="WSHttpBinding_IService1" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I'm sorry, I have to add more letters here so I can pass SOF's rule about having too many code in the question ..siaasd asjasjd kasjg kash jasdkus kasdashdsakdasd jasdj ldasdj asd lasd kk adjsad lasld ads kasd lald h3riew askk asdjasdj asdj asdj asd asdj asdj asdj adjsadjasd jasdj asdj adsj adsj ajdasjdasd jadj jsksk jdd   asdasd wow that's still not enought i have to add more here

Answer (score 0):

> I can not use basicHttpBinding because from what I know it's in .Net
>   4.5

It's not true.

To solve this problem check if your dates on client and server are synchronized. Just set the same hour on server and client machine.